# Check vector elements against matrix elements

Tags: matlab, vector, matrix, compare, element

What's the proper way of checking if the first occurrence any element from a vector exists in a matrix? For example if I have

```
A = [1, 3]
```

and

```
B = [ 1, 2 ; 
      1, 4 ; 
      2, 3 ; 
      2, 4 ; 
      3, 4 ];
```

I should get something that returns the indices of matrix B where this condition is met. So for the example I should get.

indx = [1, 1]

I'm using MATLAB R2012a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to search for **all** elements of vector `A` in matrix `B` you may use `bsxfun`:

```
tmp = bsxfun( @eq, B(:), A );
```

This comparison disregards the matrix shape of `B` and treats it as a stack of elements. In your example `B` has `10` elements and `A` has `2`, therefore `tmp` is a **binary** matrix of size `10x2` with `true` wherever `B` equals an elements of `A`.

To find the first element of `B` that equals **any** element of `A` you simply do

```
idx = find( any( tmp, 2 ), 1, 'first' );
```

To convert the linear index `idx` into a row-col pair into `B`

```
[r c] = ind2sub( size(B), idx );
```

Cheers!

Comment: I keep forgetting that myself, but there is no need for `ind2sub`, `find` can return the row and column indices too.

Comment: @EitanT - in this case `ind2sub` is mandatory - since I "flattened" `B` while creating `tmp`.

Comment: Ah, I missed the `B(:)` part.

Comment: Instead of looking for the first occurance, how would I snake my way through matrix B. I want to alternate between comparing the first and second column of each row. For example, 1)start with A = [1 3], 2)use 3 and find [2 3] in B , 3)use 2 and find [2 4] in B, 4)use 4 and find [3 4] in B, 5)use 4 and find [1 4] in B, 6)use 1 and find [1 2] in B. Right now I'm trying this using a loop and alternating column indices but nothing is working.

Comment: @roldy I'm completely at lost - what are you asking? is this part of your question or a new one? Is your `B` actually representing a tree-structure? are you looking for paths in the tree?

Comment: @roldy - you go ahead and do so. comments are not the place for questions... Let other people see it - they might come up with better answers.

Comment: Maybe I should explain why I need to do this. I have a 4 X 2 cell array where each row represents a segment of a line described by two coordinates. The goal is to connect the segments(rows) by looking for common vertices, these will either show up in 1st or 2nd column. I've done this comparison but the "assembly" of an array that contains all the vertices (no repeated vertices) is a bit difficult. This link contains the files that make this run. http://www.datafilehost.com/download-fd3cc491.html. The final output should be '4  -1' '3  0.25' '2.5  1' '-1  3.5' '-2.5  4.75'

Answer (score 3):

you can use [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html):

```
vec=ismember(A,B);
```

or

```
vec=ismember(B,A)
```

depends what you want exultantly (elements of A are found in B or vice versa).
Then you can just

```
[row col]=find(vec,1, 'first')
```

to get the index position

Comment: Why do you use A(1)? The vector and the matrix above were arbitrary. I'm not guaranteed that the first element in A will be the first occurance in B. Essentially I need something like this. [row col]=find(A(1)==B,1, 'first') and [row col]=find(A(2)==B,1, 'first'). I need the [row col] of B for the first check that gets hit. A(1) may trigger find or A(2) may trigger. By trigger I mean satisfy the condition of A(1 or 2) == B.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood you. you can use `ismember`, I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 2):

Have to tried using `strfind` command in Matlab.

You can try something like this :

```
res = strfind(B(:)',A)
```

This will give all the occurance of A in B. So, the first occurance would be `res(1)`

Hope it helps

Comment: I decided that I'm going to take a different route and try and work from the intersection points cell array. But to no surprise I am at a stand still. I posted a new question in regards to this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431860/check-if-entries-in-a-cell-are-in-a-cell-arrary.