# Check if entries in a cell are in a cell arrary

Tags: matlab, cells

Suppose I have a cell

`A = {[3,0], [2,1]}`

and a cell array

```
B = {[4,-1],[3,0];      
      [-1,4],[-3,5];
      [3,0],[2,1];
      [2,1],[-1,4]}.
```

I want to find the indices where both the first or second entry in `A` shows up in `B` excluding the row in `B` where both entries of `A` show up.

In this example I should get something like `[1 4]` for the rows in `B`. I've been trying to figure this out using `cellfun` and `cell2mat` but keep stumbling.

Comment: Why would you get `[1 4]`? `A{1}` shows up in `B{1, 2}` and `B{3, 1}`, while `A{2}` shows up in `B{1, 4}`, and `B{3, 2}`. So why would the solution be `[1 4]`? Also, it would be nice if you re-phrased the question to use integers. The decimal numbers don't appear to be essential to the problem, and integers are much easier on the eye.

Comment: The solution is [1 4] because I'm looking for the rows in B (besides the row that both are in) that these values are in. I should of rephrased it to say that instead of indices.

Comment: I would rephrase it to say that you want to find what rows in B have exactly one element in common with an element in A.
(Or at least one element, but not all)

Comment: @roldy Understood. I've provided a solution that should be reasonably efficient.

Comment: @roldy What about the case where the first entry in `A` shows up twice in the same row of `B`? Do you want to include or exclude this case from your list of indices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would approach this problem by converting my cell arrays to numeric arrays of appropriate dimensions, and then use `ismember`.

The following example illustrates how this method works on the example cell arrays in the question:

```
%# Build the example cell arrays
A = {[3,0], [2,1]};
B = {[4,-1],[3,0];      
     [-1,4],[-3,5];
     [3,0],[2,1];
     [3,0],[3,0];
     [2,1],[-1,4]};

%# Get the number of elements in A, and the length of the first element
K = size(A, 2);
J = length(A{1, 1});

%# Convert cell arrays to usefully shaped numerical matrices
ANumVec = cell2mat(A);
ANum = reshape(ANumVec, K, J)';
BNum = cell2mat(B);

%# Find matches of 1*2 vectors in ANum in sets of two columns of BNum 
I1 = ismember(BNum(:, 1:J), ANum, 'rows');
I2 = ismember(BNum(:, J+1:end), ANum, 'rows');
I3 = ismember(BNum, ANumVec, 'rows');

%# Find all indices where there was exactly 1 match (ie omit cases of no matches and cases of 2 matches)
MainIndex = I1 + I2;
MainIndex(I3) = 0;
Soln = find(MainIndex > 0);
```

Some points:

1) This method finds the indices of all rows in `B` where an element of `A` lies in the first or second column of `B`, *excluding* the situation where `A` corresponds exactly to a row of `B`.

2) This method will fail if there are multiple rows in `A`. However, it is robust to `A` being a cell array of size 1*N, where N denotes some arbitrary number of 1*2 numeric vectors. Thus the single row limitation can be circumvented by first reshaping `A` to a 1*N cell array.

3) Equivalence is tested using the logical operator `==`. This can be dangerous with floating point numbers unless you have reason to believe a priori that your inputs will not exhibit any floating point error.

4) I can't shake the feeling that there is a much more efficient way to solve this problem, but that I'm not seeing it at the moment. :-)

Comment: This looks like this method could work for me but I won't know for sure unless I implement the row removal in B like you suggested in point 1. From the start I knew that I would need to do this but concentrated my efforts on other aspects of the code. If it's not too much trouble could you describe how to include this case. In case you're wondering the values in A are taken from B. This is done in a loop I have set up. Essentially I'm trying to "connect" these rows by their common cell value.

Comment: @roldy I've updated the answer. You could probably compact what I've done into a smaller number of lines, but the code would be less readable.

Comment: Thanks for the effort and the explaining of the method. I will fool around with this now but tomorrow I will post a link of the program in it's entirety with a detailed description of what I'm doing. Maybe then a more efficient method can be seen. I too agree that another easier method may exist.

Comment: @roldy ps, if you think this response solves your problem, then please click the tick mark next to it, which marks the question answered. I notice you haven't done this for any of the questions you've asked on Stack Overflow. Can I suggest you go back through your history and mark as answered any of your questions you feel were solved?

Comment: Yes, I will look through them tomorrow. Thanks for pointing that out. Would you be willing to look through my program if I post the link here tomorrow?

Comment: @roldy I definitely won't be online tomorrow, and to be honest, can never really know, a priori, when I'll have spare time to log onto Stack Overflow. FYI, if you're posting a full program, [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/?as=1) might be a better place to post anyway. Stack Overflow tends to be more aimed at specific questions within a given program. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

quick and dirty:

```
C=zeros(size(B));

for i=1:size(C,1);
    for j=1:size(C,2);
        for k=1:length(A);
            C(i,j)=C(i,j)+isequal(B{i,j},A{k}); % Does element k of A match?
        end;
    end;
end;

find(sum(C')==1) % Sums the rows and finds the rows with only one match
```

Comment: Hmm, wish there was a more compact way to do this because my data set may contain upwards of 1000 elements. I would hate to perform this loop on every element. I'll try it out and see how it goes.

Comment: You could go through and find the rows that match `A{1}` and then find the rows that match `A{2}` and then remove any rows that appear in both lists.